# upgrade B+ to python 3.7

Tags: python, update

I have a B+ running rasp stretch and I am attempting to [follow this tutorial](https://www.alauda.ro/2019/01/how-to-install-python-3-7-on-raspberry-pi/) to upgrade to 3.7 but I have an issue at the this step:

```
./configure –prefix=/usr/local/opt/python-3.7.0
make -j 4
```

Any ideas to get around this?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ tar xf Python-3.7.0.tar.xz
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd Python-3.7.0
pi@raspberrypi:~/Python-3.7.0 $ ./configure –prefix=/usr/local/opt/python-3.7.0
configure: error: invalid variable name: `–prefix'
pi@raspberrypi:~/Python-3.7.0 $ make -j 4
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Comment: Why not just flash Raspbian Buster - it comes with Python 3.7

Comment: ah Ok, can you post an answer for how to upgrade to buster?

Comment: You can't upgrade - you have to re-flash

Comment: @CoderMike that's not strictly true. You can upgrade from Stretch to Buster but it may not work for everyone and Buster may not include all of the packages in Stretch. It's not recommended but it is possible. You may miss new packages, you may break things (like the Google AIY stuff).

Comment: I ended up [following this post](https://howchoo.com/g/ywmxmza2ndf/raspbian-buster-install-or-upgrade) to upgrade to buster

Answer (score 1):

it's `--prefix` not `-prefix` (if you copy-pasted, just remove the `-` and manually type `--` (who hyphens))